# ag grid edit color of each row depends on its key

Tags: javascript, styles, ag-grid

i using ag grid, i have tasks to diplay each task has a status (DONE,RELEASED,ACCEPTED ...)
and i want to show in grid. each row display a task and i want to appear in such color that i defind in js file

```
    $scope.status=
    [
    {'status:DONE','color:red'}, ...
    ]
```

and so on.

the data about task i  read it from db so in gridOptions the rowdata is null

````
```
$scope.gridOptions = {
            columnDefs: columnDefs,
            rowData: null,
            angularCompileRows: true,
            floatingFilter: true,
            rowSelection: 'single',
            animateRows: true
};
```
````

in other function i get data from database and i write

```
`$scope$scope.gridOptions.api.setRowData($scope.tasksList);`
```

my question how can i set for each status to diplay it in a predefined color after setrowdata ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ag-grid cell styles. Based on the row status, you can attach different css classes or colors. Refer to this [link](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/cell-styles/)

Comment: thank you for your response, i can also use [https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/row-styles/]